# IE 9 page does not center

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

Page works fine in chrome, and IE 9 compatibility mode but not in actual IE 9 mode. The page is supposed to be centered. [Site](http://www.web-dezigners.com)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your main page, there's a css style defined inline on lines 100-108:

```
    <!--[if gte IE 7.0]>

    <style type="text/css">

    .clearfix {display: inline-block;}

    </style>

    <![endif]-->
```

Those conditional comments will turn your `clearfix` classed elements from `display:block;` to `display:inline-block;` on IE 8 and 9.  If you check it in IE7, they center just fine.

Just get rid of these lines, and you'll be up and running.

Comment: thanks a lot. takes a fresh pair of eyes to find these silly problems. trying to make stuff cross browser compatible ending up creating new problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's your `.clearfix` and `.clearfix::after` styles.

When I remove those, it works fine.